# run javascript button c#

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio

how do i run javascript in c#

I have the following javascript but when I click on the c # button it does not run

```js
<script   type="text/javascript">
        function ShowMessage() {

            demo.initChartist();

            $.notify({
                icon: 'ti-user',
                message: "Funciona <b>Alexander Escobar</b> ."

            }, {
                type: 'success',
                timer: 50,
                placement: {
                    from: "bottom",
                    align: "right"
                }
            });

        }
 </script>
```

code button c#

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Button1.Attributes.Add("onClick", "ShowMessage()");
    }
```

Comment: What happens? Do you get a client side JavaScript error? Do you get a server side error? Does the page reload? You need to be more descriptive of your issue.

Comment: Shouldn't this `this.Button1.Attributes.Add("onClick", "ShowMessage()");` be added to the button on creation, not in the click event? Also, if this is an ASP.Net Button, are you adding `runat="server"`?

Answer (score -2):

You don't really need the `Button_Click` handler because you'd be assigning two handlers (**C#** and **JS**) instead of just one (which is what you need). I'm pretty sure you can do something like this instead:

```
Button1.Attributes.Add("onclick","ShowMessage();");
```

Notice that `"ShowMessage();"` has a semicolon in the parameter text. You should also take note that this solution assigns **one** JavaScript handler client side. Pressing F12 and inspecting the button on your ASP page should show an `onclick` attribute with the method `ShowMessage();`.